# Ways to find maximum digit

Tags: c++

Currently my mini algorithm looks like this.

```
int a,b,c,max;
cout <<"Enter 3 digits: \t";
cin>>a>>b>>c;
if(a>b && a>c)
    max=a;
else if(b>c && b>a)
    max=b;
else
    max=c;
cout <<"max: "<<max<<endl;
```

It works but Is there any other way to find maximum of 3 digits?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C++11, you could do this:

```
int max_value = std::max({a, b, c});
```

It makes use of an overload of [`std::max`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max) which takes `std::initializer_list<T>` as argument. It implies you could pass **more than 3 arguments**!

```
int max_value = std::max({1,2,3,4,5,6,98,10});
```

Demo : http://ideone.com/FLifw

Comment: Nice! +1. It's high time for me to get familiar with C++11.

Comment: How do I know that my C++ version is 11?))

Comment: @epic_syntax: Which version of which compiler are you using? If you're using GCC, try compiling your code with `--std=c++0x` option; it may work if you've updated version.

Comment: @Downvoter: What is the reason? please leave a comment as well when you downvote.

Comment: @epic_syntax: It looks like you've downvoted? (I saw the timestamp: an unupvote, a downvote and accept, all happened at almost same time).

Answer (score 2):

For [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b):

```
int max = std::max( std::max( a, b ), c );
```

For [c](/questions/tagged/c) you could write your own `max` function or use `MAX` macro ( **not** defined in the standard, but probably "supported" by you compiler)

Answer (score 2):

```
max = a; 
if(b>max) max = b;
if(c>max) max = c;
```

would this work?

Answer (score 0):

In C++, you should probably use `std::max()`:

```
const int max_value = std::max(std::max(a, b), c);
```

Comment: @epic_syntax my C++ professor said "const! const! const! always const".

Answer (score 0):

```
int max=a>b?(a>c?a:c):(b>c?b:c);
```

or

```
printf("greatest no: %d"(a>b)?((a>c)?a:c):((c>b)?c:b));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Find Maximum of 7 integer Number
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
//Declaration   
int a,b,c,d,e,f,g,max;
    cout<<"Enter Values : ";
    cin>>a>>b>>c>>d>>e>>f>>g;
    max=a;
    if(b>max)
        max=b;
    if(c>max)
        max=c;
    if(d>max)
        max=d;
    if(e>max)
        max=e;
    if(f>max)
        max=f;
    if(g>max)
        max=g;
    cout<<"Maximum is : "<<max;
    return 0;
}
```